# Open links in new window with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

hi I have a Js image changer with corresponding links how to I open links in new window ?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        //#1 SPECIFY number of slideshows
        var number_of_slideshows=3

        // (2000=2 seconds)
        var interval=3500

        //#3 SHOULD each slide be linked to a unique URL
        var linked=1

        var slideshows=new Array(number_of_slideshows)
        for (i=0; i <number_of_slideshows; i++)
        slideshows[i]=new Array()

        //#4 SPECIFY image paths of 1st slideshow
        slideshows[0][0]='images/brownie.png'
        slideshows[0][1]='images/land.jpg'
        slideshows[0][2]='images/palmer.jpg'
        slideshows[0][3]='images/add.jpg'


        var slidelinks=new Array(number_of_slideshows)
        for (i=0; i <number_of_slideshows; i++)
        slidelinks[i]=new Array()

        //#5 SPECIFY urls of 1st slideshow
        slidelinks[0][0]='http://www.browning.com'
        slidelinks[0][1]='http://www.lakelandfishery.com'
        slidelinks[0][2]='http://www.palmeroni.com'
        slidelinks[0][3]='http://www.palmeroni.com'



        function clickredir()
```

{
     window.open("http://www.browning.com","","")
      window.open("http://www.lakelandfishery.com","","") 
       window.open("http://www.palmeroni.com","","") 
        window.open("http://www.palmeroni.com","","")
}

```
</script>

          <script>

        var maininc=0
        var subinc=0

        if (linked)
        document.write('<a href="javascript:clickredir()"><img src="'+slideshows[0][0]+'" name="multislide" border=0></a>')
        else
        document.write('<img src="'+slideshows[0][0]+'" name="multislide">')

        function slideit(){
        subinc= (subinc<slideshows[maininc].length-1)? subinc+1: 0
        document.images.multislide.src=slideshows[maininc][subinc]
        }

        function setslide(which){
        clearInterval(runit)
        maininc=which
        subinc=0
        runit=setInterval("slideit()",interval)
        }

        runit=setInterval("slideit()",interval)

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open new window in JS use [window.open](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/window.shtml)

Example: `window.open(url, "", "toolbar=1, resize=1, scrollbars=1, status=1")`

---

**Edit**

```
if (linked)
  document.write('<a href="javascript:window.open(slidelinks[0][0],"","")"><img src="'+slideshows[0][0]+'" name="multislide" border=0></a>')
else
  document.write('<img src="'+slideshows[0][0]+'" name="multislide">')
```

---

**Edit 2**

```
if (linked)
  document.write('<a href="javascript:clickredir(0,0)"><img src="'+slideshows[0][0]+'" name="multislide" border=0></a>')
else
  document.write('<img src="'+slideshows[0][0]+'" name="multislide">')
```

Pass some parameter in clickDir() method to know which url to open. Decide it yourself what you want to pass. And then in clickdir method do like this:

```
function clickredir(i,j) 
{ window.open(slidelinks[i][j],"","") }
```

It's just a sample code you have to modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: do i put it in here slidelinks[0][0]=window.open(http://www.browning.com, "", "toolbar=1, resize=1, scrollbars=1, status=1")

Comment: No write it where you wanna open your url in new window. May be in your clickredir() function.

Comment: function clickredir()
        {
        window.location=slidelinks[maininc][subinc]                                       
  window.open(url                                                             }

Comment: no. It should be: `function clickredir() { window.open(url,"","") } `

Comment: thanks do i in close the url with "" or '' and do i just repeat that line for the 3 links or fill in the links in the 1 line in the "" ? sorry i'm only new to Javascript

Comment: Yes enclose url in "" and write 3 times for 3 urls.

Comment: function clickredir() 
{
  window.open("http://www.browning.com","www.lakelandfishery.com","http://www.palmeroni.com","http://www.palmeroni.com")
   
    
} this only opens the first link no matter what pic you click and when i repeated the the line 3 times it opened all links at once

Comment: No it should be: `window.open("browing.com","",""); window.open("www.lakelandfishrey.com","","");window.open("ht","","");`

Comment: i edited the function like that but it opens all urls at once not just the one when i click , i edited the main question

Comment: call only one window.open(url,"","") where you wanna open new window. may be on click of different links. Then on onclick of that links call  window.open with respective url.

Comment: sorry Harry you lost me now ,any chance please of a code example :)

Comment: i replaced my if else with yours and now it wont redirect anywhere